# Jquery event seems to append data to variable within the callback function

Tags: jquery

In a JQuery event (on click), I declare a variable inside that event and every time I hit the related event the data gets appended to the variable

```
$('select').on('blur', function () {
    let otherd = $('option:selected').text();
    if (otherd === 'Bank holidays' && otherd !== 'Sat' || otherd !== 'Sun') {
        nbrOfBankHolidays.push(1);
        console.log(otherd);
    }
 });
```

This is not an issue but I'm curious about the behavior because I wasn't expecting that it would work this way... i.e. every time I would hit that event I thought the variable would be reset with the new value and not appended to the previous value. It seems to stay in memory... I have a print screen of a debug where we see the actual result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoSib.png)

Comment: Where are you appending the values? Are you sure that your select doesnt ave an option with value "Bank holidaysBank holidays"? The code you have shared is not responsible for the selected text of your select element.

Comment: You might need parenthesis around the OR portion of your condition.

    `(otherd === 'Bank holidays' && (otherd !== 'Sat' || otherd !== 'Sun'))`

Comment: Add a screenshot of your `<option>` html too. When you call `.text()`, it gets all of the text within the object and its children elements.

Comment: @Steve, the html is the following one: <td>
                                <select class="col-md-8 md-textarea form-control wdays">
                                    <option value=""></option>
                                    <option value="Day off">Day off</option>
                                    <option value="Bank holidays worked" id="bkh">Bank holidays</option>
                                    <option value="Sick">Sick</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>

Comment: Nawed Khan I'm not appending any value anywhere, just using that function  to push some value in an array if the variable mentioned is === to a certain string... the array is then passed to the backend using ajax... on submit

Comment: @NawedKhan it is in a way because it scans all the selected options and returns their values concatenated... but indeed nothing has been appended here you are right, the variable only contains the returned values previously explained

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the `.val()` of the selected `<option>` instead of the `.text()`.

Comment: it doesn't return value using val(), only text() works here

Comment: regarding the if condition you are right I forgot to wrap (otherd !== 'Sat' || otherd !== 'Sun')... thanks for that...

Comment: I think I got it, actually this piece of code is responsible, $('option:selected').text(); when two items are selected it scans all the options selected and concatenates them... then of course the value passed to the variable is all the selected items... so nothing to do with some data appended to an existing variable...Sorry guys about that

Comment: and this code does the work ( it actually selects only the actual selected option and not all of the selected ones...) :  let otherd = $(this).find(':selected').text();